# How to use a local version of a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'd like to use the local version of a gem without installing it. I have the released version of the gem installed though. I'm not using bundler either.

For example, I have a gem `foo` installed. I've cloned its source, modified the source and built the gem (but not installed). How do I include this new local version into my ruby file?

Comment: With bundler it's easy.

Comment: Is it not possible without it - this is really just for a simple script.

Comment: If you copied your modified gem source into GEM_PATH, then ruby would be able to pick it up. However, there's this issue of forcing ruby to choose specific version of a gem - precisely the reason why bundler was born.

Comment: Ah, there's your idea: play with the paths. LOAD_PATH, GEM_PATH, etc. (add location of your local gem there). No guarantees, though :)

Comment: @MohamedOsama what `Gemfile`? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-I` option in ruby.

> -I directory
>
> Used to tell Ruby where to load the library scripts.
>                       Directory path will be added to the load-path variable
>                       ($:).

```
ruby -I /path/to/your_gem/lib <your_file.rb>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most gems have a file (usually loading a module) that loads all the associated objects. It should be at the root of the lib folder. The module usually has the name of the gem.

Either download the gem source code, or [unpack the gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-unpack) and then use a require statement pointing at the location of that file. For example for a foo gem it might look something like

```
require 'path/to/foo/gem/lib/foo'
```

The objects defined in the gem, should then be available to the current environment.